# How to get a direct darshan, avoiding all the queues, in Tirupati Balaji Temple?

Tags: india, temples, pilgrimages

This is specific to India and Indian people. My wife and I visit Tirupati Balaji Temple regularly and take darshan after going through long queues. Even for a Rs 300/- ticket queue there is significant crowd. 
This year we have our one year old son who will not be able to tolerate the crowd. Is there a way to get a direct darshan, avoiding all the queues?

Comment: So I've searched this term, and not would up any wiser what it is you are paying/queueing for. I'm sure anyone who can actually answer the question understands, but I'd be interested in an explanation.

Comment: As I have said in the question, it is specific to India and Indian people. It requires you to have a basic understanding of how Indian temples operate. Basically, we have to view a deity for which there is a long queue. We want to avoid that queue. I want to know if the temple provides such a provision.

Comment: Please also suggest any particular time and day when the crowd is minimum.

Comment: As far as I remember, there was a separate entry for mothers with infants. They would wait at the main entrance (probably were given a specific time slot) and I've heard that this kind of darshan is hasslefree for the whole family with infants. See if [this](http://gotirupati.com/infant-entry-in-tirumala/) helps.

Comment: Respectfully, is this travel related? Since we/I don't understand the references, I don't know whether there is any travel component to it.

Comment: I was expecting this comment especially from a non-Indian.Yes, it is travel related. Tirupati temple attracts the most pilgrims in India. The problems are unique. It is similar to asking about some facility in Paris if one is going to visit it . Recently I read a question about keeping things safe on a beach. That was upvoted number of times. Seemed more like a lifehack question than a travel one.

Comment: Excellent. I will not VtC and have, in fact, upvoted it as an original question that may affect many people, just not me. :)

Comment: You can visit it if you are in India. It would be quite an experience.

Comment: @smyslov: Although my son is over one year, your answer will be helpful for others. Convert your comment into an 'answer'. I'll 'Accept' it.

Comment: Have you tried pre-booking through https://www.ttdsevaonline.com/?

Comment: So if you are rich, you can buy access to see God? Wow.

Comment: @edocetirwi: Yes. Pretty much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I remember, there was a separate entry for mothers with infants. They would wait at the main entrance (probably were given a specific time slot) and I've heard that this kind of darshan is hassle-free for the whole family with infants. See if [this](http://gotirupati.com/infant-entry-in-tirumala/) helps.

Answer (score 3):

It is very difficult to get direct darshan. I heard there is a provision of special direct darshan if you have a letter from any central/state minister. Or the pedestrian pilgrims have provision to get direct darshan.
Anyway the crowd depends on the time of the year you are visiting. I visited there in December,2013 with a Rs : 50 ticket. We had to wait for three hours. I think with Rs 300 ticket you will have to wait much less. Anyway try to book on weekdays rather than weekends to avoid the large crowd from Bangalore, Mysore etc. Good luck.

Comment: Wow central/state ministers gives you direct access to God :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a special privilege for the devotees with infants. They have a separate Q-Line. Hope [this](https://tirupatitirumalainfo.com/darshan/) post might help you:

> **Special Entry Darshan for Parents with Infants ( Below 1 Yr)**
>
> »  Darshan Token Price:  Free
>    » Darshan Timings:  11:00 AM to 8:00 PM (Monday to Sunday)
>    » Reporting Place:  Supatham (It is between Vaikuntam Queue complex-I and Hathiramji Mutt)